# Xcode label causes line break in middle of word

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard

I've been working with a label on a storyboard and can't seem to get it to behave correctly.  I have my lines set to 0 because I display a couple different things in the label, depending on what the user clicked before.  3 or 4 words will display fine and on multiple lines, but when I get to a larger single word it will break the word in half.  I don't won't it to do this, I just want it to resize and stay on a single line if it's only one word.  Any ideas how to do this?  I already have it working so that it will auto resize long text to fit there, the only problem is this.

Answer (score 0):

If a UILabel is too small in its width, it cuts off the last part of the text or breaks its content into another line. As one word does not break into half automatically it can't be displayed entirely and therefore is cut off at its end.

In order to solve your problem I have some suggestions:

1. Change the number of lines to at least 1
2. Update your frames
3. Resize the UILabel so it can display the entire word.
4. Take a look at your constraints, as they might force the UILabel to resize under certain conditions.

I hope this might help you.